# ¿Como se puede llenar una tabla de 1 en 1 por medio de un botón?

Tags: javascript

Me pueden ayudar que envés de que esta tabla se llene dinámico, que se llene dato por dato según den clic al botón, necesito llenar una tabla asi que cada que des clic a su botón se agregen los datos a una tabla.
Es una función que quiero hacer para poder llenar un carrito de compras, y algo asi necesito para poder realizar el proceso siguiente de hacer las sumas y poder mandar los datos al backend.

```js
function addTable() {
var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("metric_results")
var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

table.border = '1'
table.appendChild(tableBody);

var heading = new Array();
heading[0] = "Tipo de Solicitud"
heading[1] = "Grupo A"
heading[2] = "Grupo B"
heading[3] = "Grupo C"
heading[4] = "Total"

var stock = new Array()
stock[0] = new Array("Carros", "88.625", "85.50", "85.81", "987")
stock[1] = new Array("Colores", "88.625", "85.50", "85.81", "989")
stock[2] = new Array("Numeros", "88.625", "85.50", "85.81", "990")
stock[3] = new Array("Peticiones", "88.625", "85.50", "85.81", "991")

//COLUMNAS DE LA TABLA
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
tableBody.appendChild(tr);
for (i = 0; i < heading.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement('TH')
    th.width = '75';
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(heading[i]));
    tr.appendChild(th);
}

//FILAS DE LA TABLA
for (i = 0; i < stock.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    for (j = 0; j < stock[i].length; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD')
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stock[i][j]));
        tr.appendChild(td)
    }
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
}  
myTableDiv.appendChild(table)
}
```

```html
<div id="metric_results">
<h2>CARGANDO DATOS DINAMICAMENTE</h2>
<input type="button" id="create" value="Click Aquí" onclick="Javascript:addTable()">
</div>
```

Comment: _Este codigo lo tome de una pregunta que encontre aqui en la comunidad._: entonces, _analiza el código_, y modifícalo conforme a lo que necesites. Tu pregunta debe contener un problema _específico_. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código, y que tu pregunta no debe parecer [un ticket para desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433). Lee [ask] y muestra un [repro] _de lo que has intentado_ hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0):

Pues creas la tabla en el html en la que a la etiqueta tbody le pones el id `tableBody`, luego creas una función que se llame cada vez que hagas click en el botón en el que le pasas un array con los parámetros y en esa función pones algo parecido.

```
var tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody"); 
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
for (j = 0; j < stock[i].length; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('TD')
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stock[i][j]));
    tr.appendChild(td)
}
tableBody.appendChild(tr);
```